# How can I check the output of a subprocess using an If-statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, subprocess, typeerror, os.system

I have already tried using os.system, startswith, etc and various other subprocess functions (check_output, run, call, ...) but I get the error
`TypeError: argument of type 'CompletedProcess' is not iterable` in line 4

Here is my code:

````
import subprocess

version = subprocess.run("wmic get os version")
if "10.0.22000" in version:
    print("You are running version 10.0.22000")
else:
    print("You are not running version 10.0.22000")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to switch your `"wmic get os version"` text to `"wmic os get version"` and then convert the result to string:

```
import subprocess

version = subprocess.run("wmic os get version")

if "10.0.22000" in str(version):
    print("You are running version 10.0.22000")
else:
    print("You are not running version 10.0.22000")
```